# How to fetch data from an API in python?

Tags: python, json, api, python-requests

I am trying to fetch competition data from an API. It has request samples on its website, but i fail to understand what I am supposed to replace their placeholders with. I am new to programming and just wasted 3 hours because i hadnt installed the request module on PyCharm. Could someone please help me with this?

```
    import http.client
    import json
    
    connection = http.client.HTTPConnection('api.football-data.org')
    headers = { 'X-Auth-Token': 'YOUR_API_TOKEN' }
    connection.request('GET', '/v2/competitions/DED', None, headers )
    response = json.loads(connection.getresponse().read().decode())
    
    print (response)
```

Comment: You need to replace `'YOUR_API_TOKEN'`. Presumably you can obtain a token from the owner of football-data.org (or through their user interface somehow)

Comment: When you sign up on their site, you should be able to generate it.

Comment: @byxor yes, but what is the X-Auth Token?

Comment: @DevangSanghani The piece of code I have posted is from their site

Comment: It is like password. You probably need to have an understanding of how APIs work with authentication.  When you signup on the site, you will get the auth token which can be used here in the code.